# Does C# return by reference or value?

Tags: c#

In the following scenario, would "Pool" be returned by value or by reference?

```
private static List<Item> Pool;

public static List<Item> GetPool()
{
    return Pool;
}
```

I want to achieve the ability to loop through the list at the time it was requested (so that another thread could add/remove items from the list but the calling thread's list stays the same so that the foreach loop does not cause an exception). If it was returned by value then it would be its own list whereas if it was a reference, I'd still be in danger of the list being modified. Please correct me if anything is wrong, this is just my understanding

Comment: Why don't you set up a test scenario and examine it in a debugger to find out?  With the 5 lines of code you posted, I think you're already 50% done with a viable test-setup.

Comment: Why don't you look at BlockingCollection or ConcurrentBag date types in .net 4.0+ - it should be suitable for your task

Answer (score 9):

All methods *always* return a value.  They can never return a reference.

> If it was returned by value then it would be its own list whereas if it was a reference, I'd still be in danger of the list being modified.

That is false.  The value being returned is not the list, but a reference to the list object, because `List` is a reference type, so any code using the value returned from this method and any code accessing that field directly are using different copies of references to the same list.

Answer (score 5):

C# always returns by value*. However, in C# most types are reference types, which means any variable of that type is a reference; and it is that reference which is returned by value.

(*) That is, until ref returns make it in (C# 7?).

Comment: C# returns reference types by reference.

Comment: @Bauss No, it does not.  It returns *all* types by value.

Comment: In his example the value returned by the function will be a reference to the list declared. That you can change the reference is a completely different talk and has to do with C#'s lack of immutability.

Comment: @Bauss Yes, the **value** returned, not the **reference** returned, because the method (like every single method always does in C#) returns a *value*.

Comment: Class values are always references.

Comment: @Bauss Yes, and those references are passed by value when returned from a method.

Answer (score 4):

The `Pool` is a variable of type `List<Item>`. Hence it holds a reference to an object of type `List<Item>` or it is `null`. That being said, when you read this value (actually that `GetPool` does), you get a reference to this object (or null).

Let's make a bit more clear what is the *main* difference between a value type and a reference type. `int` is a value type. Let's consider the following piece of code.

```
int a = 4;
int b = a;
a = 5;
```

What are the values of `a` and `b` after the above declarations and assignments have been done?

The value of `a` would be 5 and the value of `b` would be 4. Why? The first statement copies the literal value of 4 to the `a`. The second statement copies the value of `a` to `b`. Hence `b`'s value are 4. Please, pay attention here, the `a`'s four is different from `b`'s four. (It's like you have two copies of the same book. The one copy belongs to the `a` and the other to `b`). After the third statement, the value of `a` would be 5.

On the other hand a class is a reference type. Let's declare the following class:

```
public Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Let's consider now that we have the following piece of code.

```
var personA = new Person { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Barney" };
var personB = personA;
personA.FirstName = "Jack";
```

What would be the values of `personA.FirstName` and `personB.FirstName`?

They would be exactly the same, `Jack`. Why?

Because in this line

```
var personB = personA;
```

we have a *copy by reference* (since a class is a reference type). What does it mean in terms of the book's paradigm we mentioned above ?  Now it is like we have thrown the physical copies of a book and we have shared a URL, in which we can read the book. Since, we both have the same reference, when something changes in the page 30, it would be visible from both of us.