# Does `return new MyType()` return a reference to or a copy of MyType

Tags: c#

## Context

```
public class Person : IDisposable
{
    public Data _data;

    public Person() { _data = new Data(); }

    public void Dispose() { _data = null; }

    public Data GetData()
    {
        // Return a copy of the reference hoping that _data exists as long as we have a reference to it
        // (principle or garbage collection)
        return _data; // Or are we actually returning a copy of _data ??????
    }

}
```

## Question

Tell me where I'm wrong, and answer the "why".

```
Data data; // Allocate memory for a reference to a Data
Person person; // Allocate memory for a reference to a Person
using (person = new Person())
{
    data = person.GetData(); // We receive the copy of the "reference to the instance" living in the person
}
Console.WriteLine("perons._data null: " + person._data); // The instance of Data has indeed been freed by the Dispose
Console.WriteLine("data not null: " + data); // WHY is data not null even though the Dispose has been called
```

I'm wondering that because of that [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484585/11248859) stating that:

> The value being returned is not the list, but a reference to the list object, because List is a reference type

### Note

Same result if we replace `GetData()` by:

```
public Data GetNewData()
{
    Data data = new Data(); // Create a new instance of Data
    // Return a copy of the reference hoping that data exists as long as we have a reference to it
    return data; 
}
```

### Second question

If indeed the instance of `Data` is copied (returned by value) when we return if from `GetData()`, then what does a [ref return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) do?

Comment: It depends on the definition of `Data`. Is it a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: `Dispose()` is just a method, it doesn't free up anything other than the `Dispose` implements. This shouldn't be confused with a ~destructor. One thing is, C# language knows about the IDisposable interface and that's why there is syntactic sugar with `using (....)`

Comment: Assigning a `null` applies to a specific *reference* in a specific variable, not to the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question body contains a different question than your question title. Let me answer the question in the body first.

A few pictures might help understand this. Let's step through your code and have a look at the situation in memory:

```
Data data;
Person person;
```

```
Local variables             Objects
---------------             -------

person: null
data: null
```

```
using (person = new Person()) {
```

```
Local variables             Objects
---------------             -------

                            +-------------+
person: ------------------> | Person      |         
data: null                  +-------------+    +------+
                            | _data  -----|--> | Data |
                            +-------------+    +------+
```

```
    data = person.GetData();
```

```
Local variables             Objects
---------------             -------

                            +-------------+
person: ------------------> | Person      |         
data: ----+                 +-------------+    +------+
          |                 | _data  -----|--> | Data |
          |                 +-------------+    +------+
          |                                      ^
          +--------------------------------------+
```

```
}  // end of using - calls Dispose, sets person._data to null
```

```
Local variables             Objects
---------------             -------

                            +-------------+
person: ------------------> | Person      |         
data: ----+                 +-------------+    +------+
          |                 | _data: null |    | Data |
          |                 +-------------+    +------+
          |                                      ^
          +--------------------------------------+
```

Hence, `person._data` is null, but `data` isn't.

---

For completeness, let me also answer the question in your title:

> Does `return new MyType()` return a reference to or a copy of MyType.

Neither. `new MyType()` always *creates a new object* (those boxes on the right-hand side of my drawings) and returns a reference to that object.

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi, that's precisely what I was looking for. I didn't understand that `_data = null` meant to set the reference to null, and not the object it references.

Comment: @NicolasVERHELST: Exactly. You can't (easily) destroy a whole object in C#. `someVariable = ...` always just changes "the arrow" going away from `someVariable`. (At least for reference types. `struct`s are a different thing, but, fortunately, you seldom need them.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question: *"WHY is data not null even though the Dispose has been called"*

The Dispose sets the local reference to null, the copy of the reference is still in tact.

The `_data` will be freed when there isn't any rooted reference, meaning no actually running code uses this reference.

See [Understanding Garbage Collection in .NET](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net/) for more information about garbage collection.

---

A ref return returns the reference itself. So it isn't a copy. Meaning if you set the local reference to null, the other reference will be null as well

Answer (score 0):

This gets a bit complicated in terminology: Instances of classes are returned by reference, but the reference *itself* is returned by value.

Therefore, in your snippet:

```cs
Data data; // Allocate memory for a reference to a Data
Person person; // Allocate memory for a reference to a Person
using (person = new Person())
{
    data = person.GetData(); // **copy** the **reference** from person._data to data
}
Console.WriteLine("perons._data null: " + person._data); // the member of the class has been nullified. This does **not** affect the copy of the reference
Console.WriteLine("data not null: " + data); // The copy of the reference has not been touched
```

Even though `person._data` was nullified, the object it points to was and is not eligible for garbage collection, since you still have a reference to it from the local variable `data`. If `Data` was itself disposable and would be disposed, using it would likely throw a `ObjectDisposedException` but there's no guarantee or enforcement that a disposed object is in fact ready for garbage collection.

Using `ref return` is a really advanced topic (and rarely used) but in this case, it would solve your problem, because if `data` is declared as `ref Data` it would be null after the dispose.